# I am trying to use a single button to change to class of 4 different elements one after the other with several clicks

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to write some javascript to change the css of 4 different classes 1 after the other.
So I click a button for the first time i want it to change class of the first element, then a second click of the same button will change the class of a second element and then the same for the 3rd and 4th.

I have the first click changing the first element but if I add in the code with the intention for it the change the class for the second element it is changed with the first click. I've tried using separate 'if' statements and an 'else if' but it always changes all the classes together or just the first class.

FIRST TRY
With 1 count element - Even though the critcount increases to 2, with the second click it does not get access to the else part of the if statement on a second click of the button.

```
var critcount = 1;

$(function () {

  $('#criteriasubmit').click(function () {

    

    if (critcount = 1) {
      var criteria1 = document.querySelector('.criteria1');
      criteria1.classList.add('criteria1selected')
      critcount++;
     
    } else if (critcount= 2) {  *//this part of the if statement is intended to work for the second 
      click the second click*
      var criteria2 = document.querySelector('.criteria2');
      criteria2.classList.add('criteria2selected')
      critcount++;
    }


    console.log("The crit count is : " + critcount);

  })



});
```

SECOND TRY
Separate IF statements just change the class of both elements with a single click. Even though crit2count should not increase to 2

```
var crit1count = 1;
var crit2count = 1;
$(function () {

  $('#criteriasubmit').click(function () {

    

    if (crit1count = 1) {
      var criteria1 = document.querySelector('.criteria1');
      criteria1.classList.add('criteria1selected')
      crit1count++;
    }

    if ((crit2count= '1') && (crit1count= '2')) { //*even if I put this above the 1st if it still 
actives on the first 
                              click*
      var criteria2 = document.querySelector('.criteria2');
      criteria2.classList.add('criteria2selected')
      crit2count++;
    }


    console.log("The crit1 count is : " + crit1count);
    console.log("The crit2 count is : " + crit2count);
  })
});
```

I have tried different combinations of the second if statement it always activates on the first click with the 2 separate if statement methods.

I hope this is clear and makes sense, please let me know if you think you need some more info.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: `if (critcount = 1)` actually is not a comparison. You need `==`. With a single `=` you are assigning `critcount` to `1`. As follows with rest of your code.

Comment: Perhaps you are coming from a VB background? In javascript and any C derivative languages, double equals `==` is the comparison for equality symbol.

Comment: That worked!!! thank you! I have been looking at this for hours! I am student at the minute just started on html in november! Thank you! :)

Comment: The rest of your code is correct? Seems like a good student then. Impressive

Comment: Well, so far.. this assignment is due Monday at midnight so here's hoping the rest goes smoothly :)

Comment: I think "smoothly" is in cards @DanS ... Upvoted you because the rest of your logic in code form is superior than the `=` vs `==`.

Comment: tbh i'd love school if i got things like that for hw